# Consulta sql SELECT

Tags: sql

Qual comando `select` me mostra apenas aqueles comentários de um único usuário?

Por exemplo: tenho uma tabela `Post` onde guarda os comentários de cada usuário (usuario_1, usuario_2, usuario_3), porém gostaria de mostrar apenas os comentários do usuario_1.

Tabela de comentários se chama `Post`:

```
ID_POST
ID_USER (chave estrangeira para a tabela Users, campo ID_USER)
mensagem
data
```

Tabela de usuários se chama `Users`:

```
ID_USER
username
avatar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme as informações fornecidas:

```
SELECT comentario FROM comentario WHERE usuario = "usuario_1"
```

Deduzindo que o nome da coluna que armazena os comentários é `comentario`, que o nome da sua tabela é `comentario` e que a coluna que armazena os usuários é `usuario`.

**EDIT** - Devido à novos dados posteriormente informados

```
SELECT mensagem
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID_USER = Post.ID_USER
WHERE Users.username = "usuario_1"
```

Comment: acho que eu deveria ser mais especifico kkkk, tenho uma tabela users e outra tabela post, a tabela post tem coluna = id_post, coluna = chave estrangeira id_user que é o id_user da tabela users, tem coluna mensagem, coluna = data_poste, agora a tabela users tem coluna = id_user, coluna = username, coluna = avatar

Comment: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM nomeDaSuaTabela (se for Mysql). Acredito que não possa ter um SELECT exclusivo para um campo.

Comment: Caraka mano realmente era isso que estava procurando flw abraço..

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, seria isso:

```
/*Buscando pelo nome do usuário*/
SELECT * FROM Post
WHERE ID_USER = (
    SELECT ID_USER FROM Users
    WHERE Login LIKE '%Texto_da_Busca_Pelo_Login_do_Usuario%'
)

/*Buscando pelo id do usuário*/
SELECT * FROM Post
WHERE ID_USER = 'ID_Digitado_Pelo_Usuario'
```